# Excel Query - invalid number of parameter and invalid descriptor index errors

Tags: excel

I work in financial deparment of a company and want to extract data from our server (SQL) to put together reports for Board.

So I have several excel file where I use excel query to retreive data and make presentations.

I have been upgrading my querys and hit an obstacle with this one.

It was working fine with this bit of code:
   SELECT

```
  INTERNAL_REFERENCE as ref,
  CMP_CODE AS CMP_CODE,
  COUNTERPARTY_CODE AS BANK_CODE,
  TRANSACTION_CODE AS TRANS_CODE,
  CAST(CONVERT(varchar(10), AMO_END_DATE, 110) AS datetime) AS DATE,
  SUM([AMORTIZATION]) AS AMOUNT
FROM
  [SAGE_MTC_FRP].[dbo].[LOAN_SCHEDULE] inner join [SAGE_MTC_FRP].[dbo].    [LOANS]
  on [SAGE_MTC_FRP].[dbo].[LOAN_SCHEDULE].LOAN_ID=[SAGE_MTC_FRP].[dbo].    [LOANS].LOAN_ID
WHERE
  (AMO_END_DATE>=?) AND (BOOK_DATE<?) AND
  (TRANSACTION_CODE<>'CPCA' AND TRANSACTION_CODE<>'CPCF' AND  TRANSACTION_CODE<>'RENT') AND 
  IS_DELETED=0 AND VERSION_NUMBER=1 AND CMP_CODE='MTG'
GROUP BY 
  INTERNAL_REFERENCE, CMP_CODE, COUNTERPARTY_CODE, TRANSACTION_CODE,     AMO_END_DATE
```

But when I put all code with the union all, it blows up with these 2x errors:

problem:
invalid number of parameter

invalid descriptor index

Code:

```
SELECT * FROM


(
SELECT 

  INTERNAL_REFERENCE as ref,
  CMP_CODE AS CMP_CODE,
  COUNTERPARTY_CODE AS BANK_CODE,
  TRANSACTION_CODE AS TRANS_CODE,
  CAST(CONVERT(varchar(10), AMO_END_DATE, 110) AS datetime) AS DATE,
  SUM([AMORTIZATION]) AS AMOUNT
FROM
  [SAGE_MTC_FRP].[dbo].[LOAN_SCHEDULE] inner join [SAGE_MTC_FRP].[dbo].    [LOANS]
  on [SAGE_MTC_FRP].[dbo].[LOAN_SCHEDULE].LOAN_ID=[SAGE_MTC_FRP].[dbo].    [LOANS].LOAN_ID
WHERE
  (AMO_END_DATE>=?) AND (BOOK_DATE<?) AND
  (TRANSACTION_CODE<>'CPCA' AND TRANSACTION_CODE<>'CPCF' AND  TRANSACTION_CODE<>'RENT') AND 
  IS_DELETED=0 AND VERSION_NUMBER=1 AND CMP_CODE='MTG'
GROUP BY 
  INTERNAL_REFERENCE, CMP_CODE, COUNTERPARTY_CODE, TRANSACTION_CODE,     AMO_END_DATE

UNION ALL

SELECT
    CL_CODE as ref
    ,LEFT([ACC_CODE] , 3) AS CMP_CODE
    ,[COUNTERPARTY_CODE] AS BANK_CODE
    ,RIGHT([CL_DESCRIPTION] , 3) AS TRANS_CODE
    ,CAST(CONVERT(varchar(10), [END_DATE], 110) AS datetime) AS DATE
    ,[CL_AMOUNT] AS AMOUNT
FROM 
[SAGE_MTC_FRP].[dbo].[CREDIT_LINES]
WHERE 
(END_DATE>?) AND
RIGHT([CL_DESCRIPTION] , 3)='PPC'
) AS DATA
ORDER BY REF
```

Answer (score 0):

If both queries run by there self, you could use something like:

```
 DECLARE @result TABLE(
 [ref] NVARCHAR(50),
 [CMP_CODE] NVARCHAR(50),
 [BANK_CODE] NVARCHAR(50),
 [TRANS_CODE] NVARCHAR(50),
 [Date] DATE,
 [AMOUNT] DECIMAL(10,2)
)
INSERT INTO @result
        ( ref ,
          CMP_CODE ,
          BANK_CODE ,
          TRANS_CODE ,
          Date ,
          AMOUNT
        )
SELECT 
      INTERNAL_REFERENCE as ref,
      CMP_CODE AS CMP_CODE,
      COUNTERPARTY_CODE AS BANK_CODE,
      TRANSACTION_CODE AS TRANS_CODE,
      CAST(CONVERT(varchar(10), AMO_END_DATE, 110) AS datetime) AS DATE,
      SUM([AMORTIZATION]) AS AMOUNT
FROM
  [SAGE_MTC_FRP].[dbo].[LOAN_SCHEDULE] inner join [SAGE_MTC_FRP].[dbo].    [LOANS]
  on [SAGE_MTC_FRP].[dbo].[LOAN_SCHEDULE].LOAN_ID=[SAGE_MTC_FRP].[dbo].    [LOANS].LOAN_ID
WHERE
  (AMO_END_DATE>=?) AND (BOOK_DATE<?) AND
  (TRANSACTION_CODE<>'CPCA' AND TRANSACTION_CODE<>'CPCF' AND  TRANSACTION_CODE<>'RENT') AND 
  IS_DELETED=0 AND VERSION_NUMBER=1 AND CMP_CODE='MTG'
GROUP BY 
  INTERNAL_REFERENCE, CMP_CODE, COUNTERPARTY_CODE, TRANSACTION_CODE,     AMO_END_DATE 

INSERT INTO @result
        ( ref ,
          CMP_CODE ,
          BANK_CODE ,
          TRANS_CODE ,
          Date ,
          AMOUNT
        )
SELECT
    CL_CODE as ref
    ,LEFT([ACC_CODE] , 3) AS CMP_CODE
    ,[COUNTERPARTY_CODE] AS BANK_CODE
    ,RIGHT([CL_DESCRIPTION] , 3) AS TRANS_CODE
    ,CAST(CONVERT(varchar(10), [END_DATE], 110) AS datetime) AS DATE
    ,[CL_AMOUNT] AS AMOUNT
FROM 
[SAGE_MTC_FRP].[dbo].[CREDIT_LINES]
WHERE 
(END_DATE>?) AND
RIGHT([CL_DESCRIPTION] , 3)='PPC'


SELECT * FROM @result ORDER BY ref
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is ancient but ran across the problem today.

To test, I removed the parameter and found that it was a security issue.  I granted the user execute permission to the SQL Procedure, and it worked without the parameter.  When I re-introduced the parameter, it continued working.

I'm far from a security expert, so I'm sure there's a better way to grant access, but this got me past the problem for now. Feel free to suggest a better solution.